# comparing values of subgroups of a group in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, grouping

I have a grouped dataframe as below which summarizes the no. of products bought by male and female customers:

```
                          Qty
prod_cat         Gender
Bags             F       2362
                 M       2346
Books            F       7070
                 M       7587
Clothing         F       3425
                 M       3748
Electronics      F       5832
                 M       6476
Footwear         F       3716
                 M       3555
Home and kitchen F       4895
                 M       5041
```

I want to get those products which have been more popular among female customers than males.So, the expected output is as below:

```
   prod_cat
0      Bags
4  Footwear
```

I have tried this below way which works, but looking for a better and simpler solution.

```
        temp =temp.reset_index()
   ...: prod_f = temp[temp["Gender"] =="F"].sort_index().drop(columns="Gender").reset_index(drop=True)
   ...: prod_m = temp[temp["Gender"] =="M"].sort_index().drop(columns="Gender").reset_index(drop =True)
   ...:
   ...: display(prod_f,prod_m)
   ...:
   ...: f_popular = prod_f[["prod_cat"]].where(prod_f["Qty"]>prod_m["Qty"])
   ...: f_popular = f_popular.loc[~f_popular.prod_cat.isnull(),]
   ...: f_popular
```

## output

```
           prod_cat   Qty
0              Bags  2362
1             Books  7070
2          Clothing  3425
3       Electronics  5832
4          Footwear  3716
5  Home and kitchen  4895

           prod_cat   Qty
0              Bags  2346
1             Books  7587
2          Clothing  3748
3       Electronics  6476
4          Footwear  3555
5  Home and kitchen  5041


   prod_cat
0      Bags
4  Footwear
```

I want to compare values of male and female subgroups within a product category group and get the rows or group where female value is more.

Comment: When you have data with multiindex, it's best practice to supply your data with `pd.DataFrame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `unstack` to create a column per gender and then use `where` to catch if Female is more than Male. It does not give the exact type of output, but you would get the information.

```
print (df['Qty'].unstack().where(lambda x: x.F>=x.M).dropna().index.tolist())
['Bags', 'Footwear']
```

or if you want dataframe, you could replace `tolist()` by `to_frame()` and get

```
          prod_cat
prod_cat          
Bags          Bags
Footwear  Footwear
```